# Styling RibbonComboBox contents

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF and the `RibbonComboBox` control has given me weeks of headaches.

I finally seem to be getting some basic functionality working. Now I'm stuck with what should be trivial but, like the rest of WPF, is not.

Here is a section of my XAML:

```
<RibbonGroup Header="Category">
    <RibbonComboBox Label="Category:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectionBoxWidth="250">
        <RibbonGallery ColumnsStretchToFill="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}">
            <RibbonGalleryCategory DisplayMemberPath="Text" MaxColumnCount="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
    </RibbonComboBox>
    <RibbonComboBox Label="Subcategory:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectionBoxWidth="250">
        <RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1" ColumnsStretchToFill="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubcategory}">
            <RibbonGalleryCategory DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Subcategories}">
            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
    </RibbonComboBox>
    <RibbonButton Label="Edit Categories" Command="local:EditCommands.Categories" SmallImageSource="Images\categories_sm.png" ToolTipTitle="Edit Categories" ToolTipDescription="Add, edit or delete categories and subcategories" ToolTipImageSource="Images\categories_sm.png"></RibbonButton>
</RibbonGroup>
```

The problem I was having is that the selection portion of the combo box drop down was only as wide as the text. (I want it to be as wide as the full drop down.)

As you can see, I added some `MaxColumnCount` and `ColumnStretchToFill` attributes. These initially seem to work, but...

1. When the code refreshes the content, the `ColumnStretchToFill` setting appears to be discarded and the selection bar is again only as wide as the selection text.
2. There is a hierarchy of `RibbonComboBox`, `RibbonGallery` and `RibbonGalleryCategory`. I could not find out why. More than one of those elements have the `MaxColumnCount` and `ColumnStretchToFill` attributes (as well as other comment attributes). How do I know which element I should set these attributes for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your goal, do the following:

```
<Ribbon>
    <RibbonGroup Header="Category" Height="100">
        <RibbonComboBox Label="Category:" >
            <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True}" >
                <RibbonGalleryCategory  ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ColumnsStretchToFill="True" MaxColumnCount="1" IsSharedColumnSizeScope="True" />
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
        <RibbonComboBox Label="Subcategory:" >
            <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubCategory}" >
                <RibbonGalleryCategory  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.SubCategories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ColumnsStretchToFill="True" MaxColumnCount="1" IsSharedColumnSizeScope="True"/>
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
        <RibbonButton Label="Edit Categories"  ToolTipTitle="Edit Categories" ToolTipDescription="Add, edit or delete categories and subcategories" Command="{Binding AddCatCommand}"></RibbonButton>
    </RibbonGroup>
</Ribbon>
```

You have to set `IsSharedColumnSizeScope="True"` in order to make the items stretch to the `ComboBox`. That insures a proper layout.

The above example shows you the difference, since i didnt set that property on your second `ComboBox`.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Here a simple **Model**

```
public class Category {
        private ObservableCollection<Category> _subCats = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Category> SubCategories => this._subCats;
    }
```

Now some **ViewModel**-stuff i put in CodeBehind

```
public partial class Window1 : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private Category _selectedCategory;
        private ObservableCollection<Category> _categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        private Category _selectedSubCategory;

        public Window1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var cat = new Category() { Name = "Category 1" };
            cat.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 1 - Subcat 1" });
            cat.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 1 - Subcat 2" });
            cat.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 1 - Subcat 3" });
            var cat2 = new Category() { Name = "Category 2" };
            cat2.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 2 - Subcat 1" });
            cat2.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 2 - Subcat 2" });
            var cat3 = new Category() { Name = "Category 3" };
            cat2.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "Cat 3 - Subcat 2" });
            this.Categories.Add(cat);
            this.Categories.Add(cat2);
            this.Categories.Add(cat3);
            this.SelectedCategory = this.Categories.First();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ICommand AddCatCommand => new RelayCommand(x => {
            var newCat = new Category { Name = "Im New" };
            newCat.SubCategories.Add(new Category { Name = "I'm new too" });
            this.Categories.Add(newCat);
        });

        public Category SelectedCategory {
            get { return _selectedCategory; }
            set {
                if (Equals(value, _selectedCategory)) return;
                _selectedCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Category SelectedSubCategory {
            get { return _selectedSubCategory; }
            set {
                if (Equals(value, _selectedSubCategory)) return;
                _selectedSubCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories => this._categories;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**Clearance**

As you might note, none of the used collections has a setter, preventing them from being overridden. If `ItemsSource` is used, the bound Collection should **not** reset, just cleared `.Clear()` and new items added as the Button in the above example will show you

Comment: Not sure why I need to set three properties to make them take the full width. But, while your changes do that, after I raise the `OnPropertyChanged` for the `ItemsSource` and the list is refreshed, the highlight bar no longer consumes the full width. So it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you add some viewmodel stuff? So i can reproduce better. Also i cannot reproduce your descibed behavior

Comment: I can try to put something together, but right now there's a fair amount of code and it's all unfinished and in transition. To clarify, if you add a button that runs code to set a new `ItemsSource`, the highlight bar still takes up the entire width of the dropdown for you? (Note in my original XAML that I am setting both the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `SelectionBoxWidth` attributes for my `RibbonComboBox`.)

Comment: Dont override your ItemsSource. Clear it and add new items. Overriding the ItemsSource will break the Binding.

Comment: What do you mean by _override_? I am binding it to a view model. But when the selected item in the Categories dropdown changes, then I have to set a new value for the subcategories. I do this by resetting the view model's subcategory list and then doing an `OnPropertyChanged` for that list.

Comment: How do you do that? My property just goes and returns the results from the database. I wouldn't want to hold the data in memory. What if it's changed by another user? So how would that work? Can I empty my collection and then repopulated it? Would that be better somehow?

Comment: @JonathanWood See my improved answer

Comment: I appreciate that, and I was reading about a similar approach. But, really I'd prefer to read the data from the database each time I need to refresh the list. However, I can play with using an `ObservableCollection` and simply repopulating it from the database when I want to read new data.

Comment: Sure you can do that. Its a good way. But use the clear/add mechanism. It's not my fault binding works best that way ;)

Comment: I appreciate your input. I have this approach sort of working as you suggested. Oddly enough, I still lose the effect of having the highlight bar span the entire dropdown width. People keep telling me how easy MVVM, but for more advanced applications, it seems to be very problematic.